# Does the Form Processor extension no longer work with Caldera Forms?

Tags: forms, formbuilder, caldera-forms

I have a Wordpress site that has been working reasonably well in terms of forms by using the Form Processor extension in conjunction with the Caldera Forms plugin.
I have - perhaps foolishly - been updating the Form Processor and Action Provider  (a requirement) extensions as updates become available, and now I find that when submitting the form  not all of the actions defined in the form processor are carried out.

For example I have a form processor that collects some details about a contact (name, address, email, etc.) and creates the contact record in Civi, adds a tag, creates a membership record and populates a custom field in the membership record.

Testing the form processor shows that it works as expected. I can configure the processor from within Caldera's interface. I can submit the Caldera form, but when checking the results all it does is create the contact record. It does not add the address, tag the record or create the membership.

Is Caldera no longer a viable option?

I am somewhat reluctantly looking at using Contact Form 7 instead. Or perhaps Form Builder? The saga of forms in Wordpress seems never-ending.